# Best way to save objects/lists in Flutter localstorage

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I've read different ways to save this information but it seems that nothing is properly written about this.
Most people recommend the use of [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) and encode/decode the list. Others use a function to map the list attribute by attribute and I don't find this professional at all.

By default, this library can save different types but lists are not between them.

So having this example:

```
final _myList = [
{one: 1, two: 2},
{one: 1, two: 2},
];
```

how could we save and get it from the local storage in Flutter?

Comment: Consider convert `{one: 1, two: 2}` into an object and follow guides about [parsing json in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51). This could be a better approach

Comment: it seems again too much information for just saving a simple object in memory. Why are there so many different ways? Which one is better?

Answer (score 2):

`main.dart`:

```
void main() {
  SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
    runApp(MyApp(prefs: prefs));
  });
}

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  MainScreen({Key key, this.prefs}) : super(key: key);
  final SharedPreferences prefs;
...
```

From `MainScreen` I pass the prefs to the rest of the pages so I load this once on my app at beginning.
This is a different page:

```
class MyState extends State<TeamsPage> {
  List _teams = [];
  SharedPreferences _prefs = null;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _prefs = widget.data["prefs"];
    _getTeams();
  }

  _getTeams() async {
    if (_prefs.containsKey("teams") == null || _prefs.get('teams') == null) {
      _teams = [
        {"name": "Team 1", "avatar": "assets/images/draw.jpg"},
        {"name": "Team 2", "avatar": "assets/images/draw1.jpg"},
        {"name": "Team 3", "avatar": "assets/images/draw2.jpg"},
        {"name": "Team 4", "avatar": "assets/images/draw3.jpg"}
      ];
      _prefs.setString("teams", json.encode(_teams));
    } else {
      _teams = json.decode(_prefs.get('teams'));
    }
  }
```